# Ionic2/Angular2 template not rendered completely

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I have a working chat app build with Ionic2 that gives me a particularly random bug/problem. It seems list items templates are sometime not completely rendered (and nothing to do with the internet connection). The bug happens when reloading the page (the app is served via Ionic CLI).

[image]

**Backend code**

Firebase `Observable` using AngularFire2 using a basic `af2.database.list('/chats', {query:{...}})`

**Template code**

```
<div
tappable
*ngFor="let chat of afChatsRef | async; trackBy: trackByFn"
(click)="gotoChat(chat.$key, chat)"
>
   <!-- custom angular component -->
   <chatitem [chat]="chat" [user]="user"></chatitem>
</div>
```

The `chatitem` is an Angular2 component. A few calculations are made inside that component in `ngOnInit()` and on `ngOnChanges()` methods (for chat title and unread status, blahblah.

**Note**

When the issue happens upon loading/reloading/refreshing my app any other remote Firebase subscription fails (ex. if i navigate to one chat to see the messages, they are not loaded). Console logs show correct list items and contents beeing loaded.

**Question**

I'm not looking for a perfect answer pub probably leads on how to debug this.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, you mentioned the the little loading circle on top of your app programmed to stop when your Observable list  length> 0,right? can you provide the piece of code that doing that? BTW, the chain reaction caused by the error happened to me also every-time i got an error somewhere in the angularfire methods...

Comment: I don't think the loader is actually a problem. I think you are correct on the fact that their is an error somewhere (although not caught or not logged that breaks everything). I've started investigating around pipes/functions i am using inside the loop (atob() btoa() for instance which seemed to reproduce the error quite well when trying to atob("?string with special chars") which allowed me to reproduce the error consistenly, whitout any warning in the console strangely enough. And about the loader its in fact `<div class="loader" *ngIf="(afChatsRef | async) === null"`></div>